# What happens to the singular values if we take absolute values of all matrix entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}$
Consider $|A|:=(|a_{ij}|)$. I have to prove or disprove that $\norm{|A|}_2=\norm{A}_2$, where $\norm{A}_2=\sqrt{\rho(A^*A)}$ and $\rho(M)$ denotes the spectral radius of a matrix $M$.

First I tried to find counterexpmples using any random matrix I could think of. Than I constructed some, where taking the abs of every entry causes maximal changes to the matrix. But nothing worked.

Then I tried to proof it. First I defined $A:=\pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}$ and formally calculated all the other matrix, hoping something nice will show up. Then I tried to do some algebra, using defintions and norm properties. But I always stuck at $|A|^*|A|$ since I do not think I can give any statements about its eigenvalues depending from $A$.

Can anyone tell me if this claim is true or not and give me a little hint how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate a counter-example, what you want are simple examples -- so select real symmetric matrices.

$A:=\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & -1\\ 
-1 & 2\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$
$\det\big(A\big) = -4- 1 = -5$ and A is traceless so
$\lambda_1 = \sqrt{5}$, $\lambda_2 = -\sqrt{5}\implies \Big \Vert A\Big \Vert_2 = \sqrt{5}\lt 3$

$B:=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1\\ 
1 & 2\\ 
\end{bmatrix} = \mathbf {11}^T + I$
$\lambda_1 = 3, \lambda_2= 1\implies \Big\Vert B\Big\Vert_2 =3$

Thus  $\Big \Vert {|A|}\Big\Vert_2\neq \Big\Vert{A}_2\Big\Vert$

Answer (score 0):

The claim is false. The simplest counterexample I believe is $A=\pmatrix{1&-1\\ 1&1}$. It is $\sqrt{2}$ times an orthogonal matrix. Hence $\|A\|_2=\sqrt{2}$. However, as $|A|=ee^T$ where $e^T=(1,1)$, we have $\big\||A|\big\|_2=\|e\|_2^2=2$.

In general, by triangle inequality, we have $\|Ax\|_2\le\big\||A||x|\big\|_2$. Hence it is always true that $\|A\|_2\le\big\||A|\big\|_2$. Equality holds if all entries on each column of $A$ happen to have the same phases, i.e. if $A=BD$ for some entrywise nonnegative matrix $B$ and some unitary diagonal matrix $D$, but this condition is **not** necessary. E.g. when $n\ge2$ and
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&C}\in M_{n+1}(\mathbb C),
$$
we have $\|A\|_2=\big\||A|\big\|_2$ for any matrix $C\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ whose entries are smaller than $\frac1n$ in moduli.

However, when equality holds **and** $A$ has an entrywise nonzero singular vector $x$ corresponding to its largest singular value, the ties in the triangle inequality $\|Ax\|_2\le\big\||A||x|\big\|_2$ will force $A$ to take the form of $BD$.